# Rename script in android (no-root)

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run a script in Android phone (no-root) to do the below task.

Get into a `camera` directory and copy all the `*.mp4` files from `Camera` to `backups` and then get into `backups` directory and to rename all the `*.mp4` to `*.nomedia` and to exit from shell.

**Code**

`cd /
cd /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/
cp *.mp4 /storage/emulated/0/backups/
cd /
cd /storage/emulated/0/backups/
mv *.mp4 *.nomedia
exit`

**Output**

With the file `VIDEO-12-03-2015.mp4` in `Camera` directory, this script will rename the file to `*.nomedia` but I am looking for `VIDEO-12-03-2015.nomedia` name and this is only happening to one file. Not working with multiple files if they are in `Camera` directory.

Please help.

Comment: You tagged your question both 'Bash' and 'Sh'. What shell are you running?

Comment: I am not sure Android 6.0 uses bash or sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all mp4's from ***/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/*** to ***/storage/emulated/0/backups/***

```
cp /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4 /storage/emulated/0/backups/
```

Trim "mp4" extension and replace it with "nomedia":

```
for f in /storage/emulated/0/backups/*.mp4; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp4}.nomedia"
done
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. You saved me its IST 0447 and working on this from 0130 IST.